# Kentico 9 Rest API : 403 Forbidden

Tags: kentico

I am using Kentico 9. I have deployed my CMS application on my location machine. I have configured Rest API as per instruction given in tutorial ([Kentico 9](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/configuring-the-rest-service)).

But still I am getting an following error:

```
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 11:51:20 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: Sorry, the page you're looking for cannot be found!

Comment: Have you configured the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` key in the web.config? A frequent mistake...

Comment: Yes. runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to  true

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of permitting access.  You can generate a hash that you add to the end of the request URL as a query string parameter, thereby providing access for non-authenticated users, or you authenticate.  The REST api has to be enabled before it will work.

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/configuring-the-rest-service

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/authenticating-rest-requests

[Basic authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) allows you to specify your username and password within the header of the request so you only need to make a single request to both authenticate and get the data.  It sounds like that's what you want to do.  [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) is a good free tool for testing REST APIs, if you need a tool.  This might help you.  It allows you to specify the username and password while testing, and handles encrypting the information and building the header attribute.  It can also spit out code samples, too, with the encrypted info provided for you.

Here are some code samples that were generated by Insomnia...

If you were building a Javascript request with basic auth it would look like this:

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://example.com/rest/macro/MyCustomMacro()");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic Aml6dGFsa3byb2Nlc356R3Ryd1VHQVNeb1BabmVjQQ==");

xhr.send(data);
```

In the C# world, the code would look something like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/rest/macro/MyCustomMacro()");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic Aml6dGFsa3byb2Nlc356R3Ryd1VHQVNeb1BabmVjQQ==");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

You may want to create a Kentico User account specifically for the API calls so you can manage the password separately from User accounts tied to actual people.  From what I have found, the User needs to have administrator rights for the REST api to work.

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden usually means that you are not authorized, the rest API usually requires you to send an authentication token in there header to identify who is requesting the resource, so check that (use postman program to test your API), otherwise could be that the handle modules tag on your web config isn't set (see documentation on extensions urls).  Try those, otherwise If you can tell us the details of your request (headers, url, etc) that will help more!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where exactly do we need to do set User name and Password for Basic authentication
As given below
With Basic authentication, you need to specify the username and password through the Authorization line in the header of every REST request. The header line consists of:

    The authentication type (Basic)
    The username and password connected by a colon (username:password), encoded using the Base64 algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Anonymous authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a credentials while connecting to rest API. Create a valid user and provide credentials while directly browsing through browser directly.

If you are trying access the api using any program then you need to pass the credentials on httpclient object. Refer the link for more information :- https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/authenticating-rest-requests